# Getting a Number that Doesn't Make Sense to Me

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Information about question: *the duration of a movie trailer is approximately normal, with mean 150 seconds and standard deviation 30 seconds.*

One part in the questions is not making sense to me and I'm pretty sure I'm doing it okay: *Any movie trailer that lasts beyond 4 minutes and 30 seconds is considered too long. What proportion of movie trailers is too long?*

Obviously, I converted to seconds and wrote:
$P(X>270)$

After I standardized it: $1-P(Z<4)$

But I don't find a $4$ on my table. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Lots of software packages do what your table does not.  One of those is telling me that the probability is  about $1/31574$. I don't know how reliable the software is, but that doesn't strike me as implausible.  I wonder if as many as $30000$ movie trailers exist? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Most books show probabilities for $z \le 2.5$ or 3. A quick Google search returned a few that go up to 3.5, none of them to 4. The reason very likely is that they only show 4 or 5 decimal places, and in that case $P(z<4) = 1.00000$. I checked on Excel, it returns
0.999968329. Yes, four standard deviations is really that far out!

Answer (score 0):

$4$ standard deviations away from the mean is so unlikely under a normal distribution that they aren't on most z-tables. You might as well simply say that the proportion of movie trailers that are too long is $0.0000$.